# Iranian Grade Average Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to handle the Iranian Grade average, regex should cover all these rules

1. Range of number should be between 0 to 20.
2. Numbers could be decimal except 20.
3. Integer part and decimal part should include one or two numbers.
4. If you use '.' you should have at least one decimal number.

examples:

20      true
19.99   true
14.5    true
12      true
4       true
0.22    true
00.02   true
10      true
14.23   true
09.23   true

---

21      false
30      false
123     false
12.222  false
09.     false
4.      false
.2      false
099     false
1.123   false

Answer (score 2):

I tested this pattern and it works:

/(?<!\S)(([0-1]?[0-9])(.)([0-9]?[0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|\d{1}|(20))(?!\S)/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If it's to match a string with an Iranian Grade Average, then this regex pattern will match only the true ones.

```
^(?:[01]?[0-9]|20)(?:[.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

> `^` : start of a line or string
> `(?:[01]?[0-9]|20)` : number from 00 or 0 to 19, or 20
> `(?:[.][0-9]{1,2})?` : optional 1 to 2 decimals
> `$` : end of line or string